# js and css cached in combres

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, combres

I have implemented combres in my website (MVC3). The problem is everytime I change something in javascript I need to clear the browser cache to reflect my changes.

If any changes are there in js and css, the browser should automatically refresh the changes. (I don't want the cache to be disabled). Is there any way of doing it?